# Term for "something which is easy to remember; memorable" - a noun

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

A "mnemonic" is a term for a system which makes something easier to remember.

Is there a term for something which is easy to remember in itself?

An example might be the sign language signs of "eat" or "drink" - these things are naturally easy to remember.
https://www.startasl.com/asldictionary/eat
https://www.startasl.com/asldictionary/drink

In a sentence using the above examples:
"While some sign language words are peculiar and easily forgotten, words such as 'eat' and 'drink' are *****s, clearly mimicking each action itself"

Comment: Please include sample sentence in your description.

Comment: Have you considered the obvious choice of (*a*) ***rememberable***? https://www.thefreedictionary.com/rememberable

Comment: Does it need to be a noun? Intuitive would probably apply.

Comment: @Kris surely 'memorable'?

Comment: @marcellothearcane I would go for *rememberable*, not *memorable* to avoid ambiguity, considering the **usage** of *memorable*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The word you are looking for is **memorable**.

Oxford dictionary defines  it as:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/memorable

Memorable (adjective)

> *Meaning:* Remembering or **easily remembered**, especially because of being special or unusual.
>
> *Usage*: "Identify colours, images, themes and a name that works for you and is easily memorable."

**Noun**: memorables

Comment: Good suggestion - the quality of being memorable. I'm thinking of a word for the thing itself. There may not be one -- seems like something in the far back of my brain, just out of reach...

Comment: I'll give it to this answer, because it does address my question. However, I don't think any one word exists... Going back to my example above about sign language, some other word which fit or a relevant: "intuit" (unfortunately this is a verb, no noun form), "instinct", used poetically "meme" in the more traditional sense, "anamnesis" (needs a "countable" form, like "anamnesia")... time to coin a phrase...

Comment: Any reference for your noun?

Comment: @AndyT no, it is out of blue.